# Apk Android - publicação

Tags: android

Eu já fiz meu código, fiz o upload para o Google Console e a APK está como rascunho.
Fiz as instruções de transformar o rascunho em publicação através da tela de criação de versão, completo os quadros e salvo.
Na hora de clicar no botão Revisar, ocorre o seguinte erro, que não está documentado em nenhum lugar: **Você deve adicionar um novo APK ou desativar um existente para criar uma nova versão.**

Update:
Usei o botão de upload, em que está escrito 'Procurar arquivos' e apontei para minha APK do tipo 'release', mas a mensagem de erro é 'O envio falhou
Você fez upload de um APK com uma assinatura inválida. Saiba mais sobre assinaturas. Erro de apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures'

Comment: Após horas de pesquisa, com a ajuda de outros porque o Google não faz muito caso de seus colaboradores para dar dicas simples de uso, foi resolvido o meu problema: basta, na hora de gerar a APK do tipo release, marcar em Signature Versions no Android Studio, V1 e V2  e não tão-somente V2, como eu havia feito. E, por outras dicas, parece não ser bom ter senhas com dígitos diferentes de letras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ***apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures*** é devido à escolha na hora de gerar a APK do tipo **release**.

É necessário marcar em *Signature Versions* no Android Studio, as opções V1 **e** V2 e não tão-somente V2.